# Jsoup : Select a row with class name containing whitespace at the end

Tags: android, css-selectors, whitespace, jsoup

I am a newbie in `Jsoup` and could not find a solution while searching for a long time. 
I have a table, in which the `tr` has a classname with whitespace at the end.

```
<table class="table_one">
<tr class="no_background ">
<td>
<b> Text comes here</b>
</td>
<td> and here... </td>
</tr></table>
```

Now, I want to access the text. When I say

```
Select("table[class=tag_std] tr[class=bgnd_1 ]")
```

it returns `empty` list. How do I get the value as

```
"Text comes here and here...".
```

Thanks.

Comment: Must you *only* select it with whitespace at the end? If you just want the `tr` with that class regardless of whitespace just use `tr.no_background`.

Comment: @BoltClock hi, yes. I need the whitespace. If is say
    tr.no_background
I get an empty list as "no_background" doesnt match "no_background " (with ending whitespace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to put your  tag inside a  tag instead of .

```
<table class="table_one">
<tr class="no_background ">
    <td>
        <b> Text comes here</b>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And I think you need this, according to your exact situation. Here is a simple example for you to test.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File input = new File("/Users/hugo/Desktop/test.html");
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Elements links = doc.select("table.table_one tr.no_background td");
    for (Element element : links) {
        System.out.println(element.text());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Text comes here
and here.
```

..

Comment: Hi, Please consider the edited post. This is my exact situation. And, i have to get the second <td> as well.